# How to ignore some items in a numbering environment?

Tags: numbering

I have a environment to number the paragraphs in it, if I have to ignore some paragraphs in the environment which needn't be numbered, eg: I want to ignore numbering of the `\lipsum[6-7]`, how to make it?

The whole codes of the environment are here:

```
 \documentclass{book}
\usepackage{mparhack}   % get marginpars to always show up on the correct side (need to compile twice)
\usepackage{lipsum}     % for dummy text

% change this to get the formatting you want
\newcommand{\parnum}{\bfseries\arabic{parcount}}
\newcounter{parcount}
\newenvironment{parnumbers}{%
\par%
   \everypar{\stepcounter{parcount}\leavevmode\marginpar[\hfill\parnum]
{\parnum}}%
\setcounter{parcount}{0}%to restart numbering in every environment
}{}

\begin{document}
\begin{parnumbers}
\lipsum[1-4]
\end{parnumbers}

\begin{parnumbers}
\lipsum[5-8]
\end{parnumbers}

\begin{parnumbers}
\lipsum[9-10]
\end{parnumbers}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I improve your codes as follows:

```
\newenvironment{parnumbers*}{%to ignore some items 
\par
\everypar{\leavevmode\marginpar[\hfill]
{}}%
}{}
```

So as I wanted, lipsum 5's number is 1
lipsum 8's number is 2
lipsum 6-7 are ignored.

**The last question is how to make it by a command, not such a environment?**

[image]

The complete MWE:

```
\documentclass{book}
 \usepackage{mparhack}   % get marginpars to always show up on the correct side (need to compile twice)
\usepackage{lipsum}     % for dummy text

% change this to get the formatting you want
\newcommand{\parnum}{\bfseries\arabic{parcount}}
\newcounter{parcount}
\newenvironment{parnumbers}{%
\par%
   \everypar{\stepcounter{parcount}\leavevmode\marginpar[\hfill\parnum]
{\parnum}}%
\setcounter{parcount}{0}%to restart numbering in every environment
}{}

\newenvironment{parnumbers*}{%
\par%
   \everypar{\leavevmode\marginpar[\hfill]
{}}%

}{}

\begin{document}
\begin{parnumbers}
\lipsum[1-4]
\end{parnumbers}

\begin{parnumbers}
\lipsum[5]
\begin{parnumbers*}
\lipsum[6-7]
\end{parnumbers*}
\lipsum[8]
\end{parnumbers}

\begin{parnumbers}
\lipsum[9-10]
\end{parnumbers}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can define a starred version of `parnumbers` environment like (My method may be rude though)

```
\newenvironment{parnumbers*}{%
\par%
   \everypar{\stepcounter{parcount}\leavevmode\marginpar[\hfill]
{}}%
\setcounter{parcount}{0}%to restart numbering in every environment
}{}
```

Then

```
\begin{parnumbers}
\lipsum[5]
\begin{parnumbers*}
\lipsum[6-7]
\end{parnumbers*}
\lipsum[8]
\end{parnumbers}
```

should do the job.

The complete MWE:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{mparhack}   % get marginpars to always show up on the correct side (need to compile twice)
\usepackage{lipsum}     % for dummy text

% change this to get the formatting you want
\newcommand{\parnum}{\bfseries\arabic{parcount}}
\newcounter{parcount}
\newenvironment{parnumbers}{%
\par%
   \everypar{\stepcounter{parcount}\leavevmode\marginpar[\hfill\parnum]
{\parnum}}%
\setcounter{parcount}{0}%to restart numbering in every environment
}{}

\newenvironment{parnumbers*}{%
\par%
   \everypar{\stepcounter{parcount}\leavevmode\marginpar[\hfill]
{}}%
\setcounter{parcount}{0}%to restart numbering in every environment
}{}

\begin{document}
\begin{parnumbers}
\lipsum[1-4]
\end{parnumbers}

\begin{parnumbers}
\lipsum[5]
\begin{parnumbers*}
\lipsum[6-7]
\end{parnumbers*}
\lipsum[8]
\end{parnumbers}

\begin{parnumbers}
\lipsum[9-10]
\end{parnumbers}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your reply.But there are still two problems:(1) it isn't exactly resolve the problem, I want ignore lipsum[6-7], so lipsum 5's number is '1', lipsum 8's number is 2,not 3.  (2)Could it be a command form, not a environment form?

Comment: But with your resolution  lipsum 8's number is 3.

Comment: OK, after I deleted \stepcounter{parcount}  and \setcounter{parcount}{0} in \newenvironment{parnumbers*}, lipsum 8's number is 2.    So there is only one question: Could it be a command, not in a form of environment ?